# How to write the check box inside the <li> tag jQuery

Tags: php, json

I am creating an e-commerce website and have to display the categories inside li tag checkbox. what I tried so far I wrote below. I couldn't get the output.

I have written inside the li tag like this but it didn't work for me.

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"><input type="checkbox"></li>
```

below I attached the full code.

Form Design(HTML)

```
 <div align="left">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" ><h4>Category</h4></li>
```

```
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"><input type="checkbox"></li>

    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function getCategory(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get_category.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var catname = data[i].catname;
                    var id = data[i].id;
                 //  $(this).prepend($('<input type="checkbox"/>'));
                  $('#categories').append('<a href="#" cid= '+ id + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + '<b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b>' + '</a>');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
               {
                console.log(xhr.message)
            }

        });
    }
```

**get_category.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,cat_name,status from category where status = '1' order by id DESC");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$catname,$status);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "catname"=>$catname,"status"=>$status);
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();

//}
```

Comment: I think you are mising the `<ul>` tag. Try to replace the `<div align="left">`

Comment: sir it is working  if i written only put li tag . like this <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"></li> . i need to put checkbox inside the li tag how to do this sir

Comment: <ul>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" ><h4>Category</h4></li>

            <li ><input class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  type="checkbox" id="categories"></li>
 </ul> but it didn't work sir

Comment: I am mobile at the moment so I cant test the code, but have you tried closing the input tag </input> some browsers dont like having it non closed when nested like this

Comment: <li ><input class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  type="checkbox" id="categories"></input></li>

Comment: <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"></li> if i write like this it is working

Comment: inside checkbox how to pass the data please help on this. can you write the code pls

Comment: Starting point is that you are writing malformed HTML. Browsers try to correct programmer mistakes but results change from browser to browser. 
Besides I cannnot understand why in jQuery loop you append a href and not an input.
Another thing to check is if the input is not visible by parent css attribute.

Comment: data display successfully one by one. but checkbox didn't displayed sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div><ul id="displayResults"></ul></div>
```

Then, inside the php file:

```
function getCategory(){
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_category.php' ,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                var catname = data[i].catname;
                var catid = data[i].id;
                var catstatus = data[i].status;
                if(catstatus){
                  $('#displayResults').append('<li id=cat_'+catid+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b><input id="cat_'+ catid +'" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true"></li>');
                }else{
                  $('#displayResults').append('<li id=cat_'+catid+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b><input id="cat_'+ catid +'" type="checkbox" value="true"></li>');
                }

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
           {
            console.log(xhr.message)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"><input type="checkbox" value="1"></li> i tried this data diplayed but checkbox not workin

Comment: What do you mean by not working? 
When checked, there's no (tick) symbol?
Or the value cannot be saved into the database?

Comment: $('#categories').append('<a href="#" cid= '+ id + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + '<b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b>' + '</a>'); any wrong inside query

Comment: At the .append function, why you use `<a>` instead of `<li>`? By the way, can you answer my previous question properly?

Comment: values store in the database sir.0: {id: 4, catname: "tv", status: 1}
1: {id: 3, catname: "fan", status: 1}
2: {id: 2, catname: "cloth", status: 1}
3: {id: 1, catname: "cap", status: 1} here values are diplaying . jquery errir i think sir

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a call to the function `getCategory`. 
Also insert the checkbox attribute in `$('#categories').append(.<a href="#" cid= '+ id + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><input type="checkbox">' + '<b>'+ catname + '<b>' + '</a>');)`

**Here my code for the checkbox view:**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

       getCategory();


    });

   function getCategory(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'get_category.php' ,
        success: function (data)
        {
          var res = JSON.parse(data);
           for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                var id = res[i].id;
                var catname = res[i].catname;
                $('#categories').append('<a href="#" cid= '+ id + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><input type="checkbox">' + '<b>'+ catname + '<b>' + '</a>');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
           {
            console.log(xhr.message)
        }

    });
}


</script>

<div align="left">
     <ul class = "list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" ><h4>Category</h4></li>

    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this can help you.